# Epsilon delta proof for the following limit

Tags: real-analysis

How do  write an epsilon-delta proof or the following limit assuming the limit is -2,

$$\lim_{x \to -1} \frac{x^2-1}{x+1}$$

Comment: For $x\ne -1$, our expression is equal to $x-1$, so finding the $\delta$ will not pose any difficulty. You will find that choosing $\delta=\epsilon$ works.

Answer (score 1):

Take any $x\neq -1$. Then it is simple to show that $$\frac{x^2-1}{x+1} = (x-1)$$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Now take $\delta = \epsilon$ and any $x$ such that $0<|x+1|<\epsilon$. You can then see that $$|\frac{x^2-1}{x+1}+2| = |x-1+2| = |x+1| < \epsilon$$ proving your point.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to factor, then you have, for $x = -1 + \epsilon$, that $(x^2 - 1)/(x+1) = (-2\epsilon + \epsilon^2)/\epsilon = -2 + \epsilon$ so now just take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, or in terms of a $\delta,\epsilon$ proof, put $\delta = \epsilon$.